# Syntax errors on Mono .Net Profile 4.5 for async/await

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, async-await

I'm trying to use async/await commands in Mono with a .NET profile of 4.5.  Everything compiles correctly, but the syntax doesn't highlight correctly and it shows an error (red squiggly underlining).

I'm using MonoDevelop 3.1.1, Mono 3.0.2 runtime, .NET Framework 4.5.  Does anyone have any idea how to fix the syntax thing?  Everything else for it works fine, but the syntax errors/highlighting is a bit annoying.

Comment: Please be sure to see jstedfast's comment on my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is "wait for the syntax highlighter to be fixed", or maybe even "go fix it yourself and submit a patch" (I *think* the core code is available?); 3.1.1 is a beta release; they ***almost certainly*** know about this issue already, but you could try logging it.

Comment: Ah, so it's not that I'm doing something wrong, but more that it hasn't been done yet?  Okay.  That's fine, just wanted to make sure.

Comment: It's actually already implemented but won't make it into 3.1.x (it'll be in 4.0, though - and 4.0 isn't really that far away). 3.1.x is more of a stop-gap version series that has a lot (but not all) of the fixes and features back-ported to the 3.0.x code-base that were easily back-portable. The syntax highlighting feature for async/await unfortunately did not make it into 3.1.x.

Comment: @jstedfast that's awesome news

Comment: Excellent news!  Is there a changelist up for either, yet?

Comment: @ashays you'll have to add `@jstedfast` to get an answer

Comment: No changelist is up yet :-(